# How can I open context menu for sheet in google sheets using only the keyboard

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that there is a way to open the google sheets context menu via the keyboard, or there was one. However, I cannot seem to find it!

For reference, this is what I am talking about (am I calling it by the wrong name? That would explain my google fu failure!)

[image: sheet context menu]

Comment: Try looking for keyboard shortcuts on the Google Sheets Help menu.

Comment: Yup. I am much obliged.

If you just copy your comment as an answer, I will expand on it and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Looking in help > keyboard shortcuts (shortcut: ctrl+/), searching for "sheet menu", I found the answer (on my system) to be alt+shift+S